# Using compile time recursion for generating prime numbers from 1 to 499

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have read that prime numbers are fixed and it is better to generate them at compile time rather than depending on runtime. So, i thought of using [Template Metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) which internally uses compile-time recursion. I am using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) method for generating prime numbers. Here is the code:

```
int prime[500]; // prime[i]==0 means i is prime

template<int n> void fillMultiple(int i)
{
    prime[n*i]=1; // n is prime, mark all its multiples as non-prime
    n*i<500?fillMultiple<n>(i+1):fillMultiple<499>(i);
}

template<> void fillMultiple<499>(int i)
{
     // do nothing
     // only used as dummy function
}

template<int n> void generatePrime()
{       
    prime[n]==0?fillMultiple<n>(2):generatePrime<n+1>(); //if n is prime,mark all the multiples of n as non-prime.
    generatePrime<n+1>();
}

template<> void generatePrime<499>()
{
     // do nothing
     // only used as dummy function
}

int main()
{
    prime[0]=prime[1]=1; // 0 and 1 is non-prime
    generatePrime<2>();

    for(int i=0;i<500;i++) // print prime numbers
            if(0==prime[i]) // if prime[i]==0, then i is prime
                    cout<<i<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When i run the code, i am getting  [`Runtime error`](http://ideone.com/Knp96)

I am not very much familiar with Template Metaprogramming.Please explain why am i getting runtime-error? If there is any error, it must have been shown at compile-time.

Comment: While I can understand this as an exercise to explore the power of templates, it's probably much easier to generate the primes in an external program and just hardcoding an array directly. After all, it's not like primes will *ever* change, so the ability to compute them again and again is worthless.

Comment: Did you try to compile with all warnings and debugging info (i.e. `g++ -Wall -g`) and did you try to use the debugger (i.e. `gdb`)? BTW, you are using an ancient version of `g++`(current one is 4.7) and GCC made considerable progress w.r.t. templates since your GCC 4.3!

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Agreed.  _Except_ as an exercise, this is abuse of template metaprogramming, and is not something that you should be doing.

Comment: This really isn't Template Metaprogramming, as it's using functions and not templates to do the work.  And the runtime error is because ideone only allows 5 second runtimes, and I let a quick copy run for 15 seconds before I decided it wasn't going to complete.

Answer (score 6):

Or:

```
int p[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 
            73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173,
            179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281,
            283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409,
            419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541,
            547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659,
            661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809,
            811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941,
            947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069,
            1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223,
            1229, 1231, 1237, 1249, 1259, 1277, 1279, 1283, 1289, 1291, 1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 1361, 1367, 1373,
            1381, 1399, 1409, 1423, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 1447, 1451, 1453, 1459, 1471, 1481, 1483, 1487, 1489, 1493, 1499, 1511,
            1523, 1531, 1543, 1549, 1553, 1559, 1567, 1571, 1579, 1583, 1597, 1601, 1607, 1609, 1613, 1619, 1621, 1627, 1637, 1657,
            1663, 1667, 1669, 1693, 1697, 1699, 1709, 1721, 1723, 1733, 1741, 1747, 1753, 1759, 1777, 1783, 1787, 1789, 1801, 1811,
            1823, 1831, 1847, 1861, 1867, 1871, 1873, 1877, 1879, 1889, 1901, 1907, 1913, 1931, 1933, 1949, 1951, 1973, 1979, 1987,
            1993, 1997, 1999, 2003, 2011, 2017, 2027, 2029, 2039, 2053, 2063, 2069, 2081, 2083, 2087, 2089, 2099, 2111, 2113, 2129,
            2131, 2137, 2141, 2143, 2153, 2161, 2179, 2203, 2207, 2213, 2221, 2237, 2239, 2243, 2251, 2267, 2269, 2273, 2281, 2287,
            2293, 2297, 2309, 2311, 2333, 2339, 2341, 2347, 2351, 2357, 2371, 2377, 2381, 2383, 2389, 2393, 2399, 2411, 2417, 2423,
            2437, 2441, 2447, 2459, 2467, 2473, 2477, 2503, 2521, 2531, 2539, 2543, 2549, 2551, 2557, 2579, 2591, 2593, 2609, 2617,
            2621, 2633, 2647, 2657, 2659, 2663, 2671, 2677, 2683, 2687, 2689, 2693, 2699, 2707, 2711, 2713, 2719, 2729, 2731, 2741,
            2749, 2753, 2767, 2777, 2789, 2791, 2797, 2801, 2803, 2819, 2833, 2837, 2843, 2851, 2857, 2861, 2879, 2887, 2897, 2903,
            2909, 2917, 2927, 2939, 2953, 2957, 2963, 2969, 2971, 2999, 3001, 3011, 3019, 3023, 3037, 3041, 3049, 3061, 3067, 3079,
            3083, 3089, 3109, 3119, 3121, 3137, 3163, 3167, 3169, 3181, 3187, 3191, 3203, 3209, 3217, 3221, 3229, 3251, 3253, 3257,
            3259, 3271, 3299, 3301, 3307, 3313, 3319, 3323, 3329, 3331, 3343, 3347, 3359, 3361, 3371, 3373, 3389, 3391, 3407, 3413,
            3433, 3449, 3457, 3461, 3463, 3467, 3469, 3491, 3499, 3511, 3517, 3527, 3529, 3533, 3539, 3541, 3547, 3557, 3559, 3571};
```

> I have read that prime numbers are fixed and it is better to generate them at compile time rather than depending on runtime.

Yes that is a good idea.
Since they are fixed means that they only need to be generated once (not every time).

> So, i thought of using Template Meta-programming which internally uses compile-time recursion.

No such a good idea.
There is a maxim recursion level set by the compilers (depends on the compiler 8>16 last time I checked (a while ago)). Best to write a one off program generate the values you want then use the code to generate the file you will compile in your real code (or cut/paste the numbers from Wikipedia like I did).

> I am using Sieve of Eratosthenes method for generating prime numbers. Here

Unfortunately that is not a template meta-program.
It works at run time.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated you can use an array of prime numbers for the first x prime numbers which is obviously faster than calculating them every time.

Although it's not an answer to your question here are some information on prime numbers which could be helpful depending of what you need:

Calculating first n prime numbers

- Sieve of Eratosthenes (which you already know of)
- Sieve of Atkin (optimized version of the algorithm from above)

Calculating the amount of prime numbers smaller than n:

- Prime-counting function
- Offset logarithmic integral
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_counting_function

Testing if prime or looking for a prime larger than a given number:

- Rabin Test
- Fermat primality test
- Solovay-Strassen-Test

Special prime numbers:

- Mersenne prime
- Twin prime

This is just a very short extract on the topic of prime numbers. Depending on what your program has to do looking into these topics might be interesting.